# WPF and VS2010 crashes on specific arabic(?) text

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I've just found symbols that WPF doesn't want to display (actually it freezes when i want it to display ones) - "ﻠ́ﭑ". When I pasted these symbols to XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="ﻠ́ﭑ" />
```

Visual Stuido has crashed. Does anybody know how to solve this? Seems that it is a microsoft wpf bug.

Comment: I repro on VS2010 SP1.  Post bug reports to connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: thanks for repro, already posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has fixed this bug on my report https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/682446/wpf-4-0-apps-i-e-vs2010-crashes-on-specific-symbols

Answer (score 1):

I can guess for such language specific Xml-unsupported characters we generally use locale based resources and refer them onto the XAML.... like this ....

1. Create a Resource (ResX) file in your project or you can reuse the Properties/Resources.resx file. In this add a resource named "MyArabicCharacter" and set it to "ﻠ́ﭑ"
2. In the Visual Studio Resource designer you have to change the Access Modifier from **Internal** to **Public**. This can be found in the top toolbar of the designer.
3. Add the namespace to your XAML View:

   ```
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"
   ```
4. The Resources can be accessed via the x:Static markup extension of XAML:

   ```
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:Resources.MyArabicCharacter}" />
   ```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: before pasting these symbols into XAML, I tried to read them from file in my WPF application - it freezes

Comment: For VS2010 not to freeze, can you defer loading that symbol till runtime?

Comment: if I'll load that symbols at the runtime _my_ wpf app will freezes, not the vs2010. I think this is a WPF bug (vs crashes because its ui based on WPF) and already reported it to ms.